# How does one store the result of a repeated query in memory in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, caching

In order to prepare for a database schema migration in which I'm adding a great many foreign key constraints with ON CASCADE DELETE, I need to run a data migration which purges orphaned rows.  That data migration currently looks like this

```
delete from child1 where parent_id not in (select id from parent)
delete from child2 where parent_id not in (select id from parent)
...
delete from child50 where parent_id not in (select id from parent)
```

(Yes, there are fifty such tables.)  `parent` is a table with enough records that it would be desirable not to have to run the id query against it many times; I'd rather run it once, store the result, and check the child table's values against the stored query result.

I've found documentation about "temporary tables", which sounds like something I'd want.  In MySQL I believe I can specify `engine=memory` as an option to the `CREATE TABLE` statement to prevent the table from being stored on disk.  I don't see a way to do the same thing in Oracle.

What are my options for memory-caching the result of the `select id from parent` query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle uses many types of caches, you probably don't need to do anything for `PARENT.ID` to be automatically cached.

The buffer cache is the largest, and most important cache, and it contains blocks of data (usually 8KB).  The buffer cache can contain blocks from tables or indexes.  Since Oracle is able to read directly from indexes, without using the table, it can cache only the index blocks for the `ID` values, which should fit nicely in memory.

The test case below shows a simple parent/child table, where Oracle caches 100% of the index on `ID`, and 49 of the 50 queries would read entirely from memory.

**Create parent/child tables, add 100K sample rows, gather optimizer statistics for best execution plans.**

```
create table parent(id number, a varchar2(100), b varchar2(100),
    constraint parent_pk primary key(id));
insert into parent select level, 'aaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbb' from dual connect by level <= 100000;

create table child(id number primary key, parent_id number,
    constraint child_fk foreign key (parent_id) references parent(id));
insert into child select level, level from dual connect by level <= 100000;

commit;

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'PARENT');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'CHILD');
end;
/
```

**The execution plan has an INDEX FAST FULL SCAN, where it uses the index like a skinny table.**

```
explain plan for
select * from child where parent_id not in (select id from parent);

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 3673552324

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |           |  1000 | 15000 |   125   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT ANTI SNA|           |  1000 | 15000 |   125   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN   | PARENT_PK |   100K|   488K|    53   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL      | CHILD     |   100K|   976K|    70   (3)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("PARENT_ID"="ID")
```

**Run the query once**

```
select * from child where parent_id not in (select id from parent);
```

**Every block for the index is cached.  The next run will read the data from memory.**

```
--Number of cached blocks for PARENT_PK: 256
select count(distinct block#)
from v$bh
where objd = (select object_id from dba_objects where object_name = 'PARENT_PK')
order by class#;


--Total number of blocks for PARENT_PK: 256
select blocks
from dba_segments
where segment_name = 'PARENT_PK';
```

There *are* ways to store results in memory, like with the result cache.  But for problem you describe you likely don't need to do anything to achieve nearly-perfect caching.